# Why is UFW blocking some allowed internal connections?

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, uwsgi, ufw

My set up is this:

- Server 1 (192.168.1.1) - nginx (load balance) - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Server 2 - uwsgi - Debian 7.1
- Server 3 - uwsgi - Debian 7.1

UFW on server 2 and server 3, is blocking certain requests coming from server 1 (nginx) and is showing up in nginx error log as "upstream timed out". Traffic between nginx and uwsgi server is all on a private network.

**This is UFW setup on uwsgi servers:**

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere on eth1           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.1.1
Anywhere (v6) on eth1      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**Example UFW block in syslog:**

> Aug 20 13:56:16 kernel: [1028623.806318] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=68:05:ca:17:c9:fb:68:05:ca:17:ca:0e:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.103 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54877 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41652 DPT=8000 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

If I disable UFW on Uwsgi servers the timeouts in nginx stops. At the moment the timeouts/blocks are mostly frequent AJAX calls (every 2mins), but not exclusively.

Comment: As I'm using port 8000 on the uwsgi servers, could UFW be using more aggressive limit on that port compared to port 80 for instance? Hence blocking too frequent requests?

Answer (score 1):

Right, I discovered that UFW was blocking INVALID packets (bad checksum I believe) coming from the Nginx server. No idea why that is happening. I solved this by removing the rule from before.rules in UFW which drops invalid packets. Website running fast again.